# How to refresh view when using signal r to update on database change

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, model-view-controller, signalr

I'm using mvc, i have a dashboard for which i have used charthelper and bootstrap admin chart. Now i want to update the data on database change. For which i'm trying to use signal R.

Before

I used repository to get data from database. So had services folder which had methods for it.

Now.

I'm not sure exactly how to do it.
But what i have done so far is created a hub class,
returning

```
public static void Send()
   {
       IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<DashboardHub>();
       context.Clients.All.updateOnDashboard();
   }
```

and on view

```
<script>
$(function () {
    // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
    var chat = $.connection.dashboardHub;
    $.connection.hub.logging = true;

    chat.client.foo = function () { };

    //debugger;
    // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
    chat.client.updateOnDashboard = function () {
        getAllDashboardUpdates()
    };
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        getAllDashboardUpdates();

        console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + $.connection.hub.id);
    })
        .fail(function () { console.log('Could not connect'); });;

    //$.connection.hub.stop();
});

function getAllDashboardUpdates() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Dasdhboard/Index',
        contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html'
    }).success(function (result) {
        //$("#refTable").html(result);
    }).error(function () {
    });
}
```

controller method

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        IEnumerable<test> newlist = null;

        newlist = GetAlltest();
        var data = dashboardService.GetDashboardData(page, User);
        if (newlist != null)
        {
            return View(data);
        }
        return View(data);
    }
```

to search for dependency

```
public IEnumerable<test> GetAlltest()
   {

       var messages = new List<test>();
       using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connString))
       {
           connection.Open();
           using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [id],[testid] FROM [dbo].[test]", connection))
           {
               command.Notification = null;
               SqlDependency.Start(_connString);
               var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
               dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

               if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                   connection.Open();

               var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

               while (reader.Read())
               {
                   messages.Add(item: new test { id = (int)reader["id"] });
               }
           }

       }
       return messages;
   }

   private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
       {
           DashboardHub.Send();
       }
   }
```

Even after doing it my view is not refreshed. I'm sure code is redundant. CAn someone show me a better way to do it. Or where i'm going wrong.

This is just one method. I have 2 charts too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly you currently establish a SingalR connection and if receive a updateOnDashboard() on the client firing a AJAX call to get a full HTML view from the server in insert it in the DOM using jQuery.

I would change that so that updateOnDashboard() also receives your new values and render these values on the client side instead calling again the server for HTML code. I would go even further and create a Javascript view-model for those values and using Knockout to databind your dashbord elements to the view-model. The updateOnDashboard() then simply needs to push these values (parameters) into the view-model and the HTML gets updates by Knockout.

I've blogged about some of this in [this post...](https://marcduerst.com/2015/11/24/build-a-signalr-connection-indicator-with-typescript-and-knockout/) or [V2 post](https://marcduerst.com/2017/02/01/signalr-connection-indicator-reloaded/)

What I don't see in your code is a peace of code that detects these data-updates. You need something on the server that detecting the changes and sends out those updateOnDashboard() calls.

Please also note that your Hub method Send() is not used anywhere. Hub methods are only used for client-to-server calls (incoming server calls). You probably don't have these so you will not need a hub method - I guess.

**Update based on your comment:**

I use SinglaR for "live" broadcasting newly added log-items to the web-clients. On the server-side I have a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) that tests for new data and broadcast them to the web-clients using SignalR. Here the code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Singleton that periodically checks the log database for new messages and broadcasts them to all
/// connected web-clients (SignalR).
/// </summary>
public class LiveMessageTicker : ILiveMessageTicker, IRegisteredObject
{
    private readonly TimeSpan updateInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);
    private readonly ILogEntriesRepository repository;
    private Guid lastLogEntryId = Guid.Empty;
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim checkSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 2);
    private Timer checkTimer;
    private readonly IHubContext hub;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="LiveMessageTicker"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="repository">The database repository to use.</param>
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException"></exception>
    public LiveMessageTicker(ILogEntriesRepository repository)
    {
        if (repository == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(repository)); }

        this.repository = repository;

        // Register this instance to in ASP to free it up on shutdown
        HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(this);

        // Get the server-side SignalR hub
        hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ServerMonitoringHub>(); 

        // Configure a Timer that calls CheckForNewMessages all 2 sec's
        checkTimer = new Timer(CheckForNewMessages, null, TimeSpan.Zero, updateInterval);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops this instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="immediate">if set to <c>true</c> immediatelly.</param>
    /// <seealso cref="IRegisteredObject"/>
    public void Stop(bool immediate)
    {
        checkTimer.Dispose();
        checkTimer = null;

        HostingEnvironment.UnregisterObject(this);
    }

    private void CheckForNewMessages(object state)
    {
        if (checkSemaphore.Wait(500))
        {
            try
            {
                // Get new log entries
                var newLogEntries = repository.GetNewLogEntries(lastLogEntryId).ToList();

                // If there arent any new log entries
                if (!newLogEntries.Any())
                {
                    return;
                }

                lastLogEntryId = newLogEntries.Last().Id;

                // Convert DB entities into DTO's for specific client needs
                var logEntries = newLogEntries.Select(l => new
                {
                    id = l.Id,
                    correlationId = l.CorelationIdentifier,
                    messageId = l.MessageId,
                    time = l.Time.ToLocalTime(),
                    level = (int)l.Level,
                    messageText = l.Message,
                    additionalData = l.AdditionalData.Select(a => new { name = a.Name, value = a.Value }).ToArray(),
                    tags = l.Tags.Select(t => t.Name).ToArray(),
                    channel = l.Channel.Name,
                    username = l.Username,
                    workstation = l.WorkstationName
                }).ToList();

                // Broadcast all new log entries over SignalR
                hub.Clients.All.addLogMessages(logEntries);
            }
            finally
            {
                checkSemaphore.Release();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This all gets started in `Global.asax.cs` there I create a single instance of the above class (which registers itself by ASP.Net for proper stopping later on with `HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(this)`).

Please note that I don't push rendered HTML-Code or Views to the client. I push the data as JSON. The server does not render it but the client does. To render it on the client I use a Javascript/[Typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) view-model that collects the incomming messages in a [Knockout ObservableArray](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html). This observablearray is bound to in HTML using the Knockout `foreach` (see [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)). So for the data-updates I don't use Razor and ASP.Net to generate the HTML. This is all part of the initially sent view which has data-bindings in it and refers my Javascript/Typescript. It's quite similar as documented in the above liked blog-post.

Comment: before I had my controller action calling interface method to get data from repository. So it was pretty simple.  Now I want to integrate with signal r. I think i need to have a signal r hub to start with. What should be in the hub method? can i call it from controller? And how do i return my view from controller ?

Comment: Updated my answer with the server-side and some more info about the client-side.

Comment: I don't have any knowledge about knockout. So waiting for more answers on it.

Comment: Knockout is just one way. You can use jQuery to to update the values into your HTML or even use your approach with getting the HTML from the server (action with Razor view). The point is that you need server code running and activelly pushing data / events from the server to the clients. The `hub.Clients.All`must be called from the server. This is done in your `Send()` method but who calls the Send() method. Some background thread / worker / etc. must call this thing so the server initiate pushes to the clients.

Comment: i have ' chat.client.updateOnDashboard = function () {
            getAllDashboardUpdates()
        };' method in script on my view it does his breakpoint in hub Send() method. Not sure if i'm doing things correctly

Comment: Did you try to set a breakpint in `dependency_OnChange`? Is this called the DashboardHub.Send() is triggered?

Comment: yes it is called. but if the ajax return is partial view. it is not called

Comment: @Marc What about this scenario on [Refreshing data periodically using SignalR rather than broadcasting to clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56899276/refreshing-data-periodically-using-signalr-rather-than-broadcasting-to-clients?noredirect=1#comment100344105_56899276)? Any help please?