# Refreshing data periodically using SignalR rather than broadcasting to clients

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, signalr

I display some of the data i.e. Sum, Average and Total on a page and want to update them after the data changed using SignalR. Most of the examples uses the following approach that broadcast all of the clients after create / update / delete methods (that change data) are executed:

```
private void BroadcastDataChange(Data data)
{
    Clients.All.dataChanged();
}
```

However, I am wondering if there is a smarter approach that let me update the data i.e. periodically refreshing without broadcast in each of the create-update-delete methods (I do not use SqlDependency, etc, juts using SignalR). On the other hand, I am not sure this kind of approach is contradictory to the SignalR logic. This is the first time I use SİgnalR and I am too confused :( Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The idea behind using SignalR is quick updates to the clients. The approach you found to broadcast to all clients as soon as the data changes seems logical, unless you want to batch them up.

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti In that case you mean that there is no way to refresh data on the page using SignalR and that means to retrieve data from database periodically for all of the clients is not suitable for SİgnalR usage. In addition to that, in order to refreshing the data on that page, I should broadcast (using SignalR) in all of the methods that can change this data. Is that completely true?

Comment: That's like the opposite of what I said :) Retrieving data from the database periodically would be similar to polling. You might just as well use AJAX for that. The idea behind SignalR is to have a persistent TCP/IP connection open with the server so that when changes happen they would be pushed to the clients (push notification). You need to wire your events that cause data to change so as to push these changes to the clients, rather than polling a database.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. In this case I think I should use SignalR by wiring all of my events that cause data to change and broadcast notification. The other idea to refresh data periodically without broadcasting and retrieving from database is not suitable for SignalR. Is that true?

Comment: @Jack what are you trying to do? SignalR exists so the browser *won't* have to poll the server. They could just use a timed loop otherwise, which would result in a hit to the database to load the data unless it was cached. The complexity increases overall and so does the load to the database.

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti Really useful information for me, I did not know polling in SignalR and as you said it can also be tried even if its inefficiency. In this case, assume that there is a StockExchange application where the stock quantities are displayed on a dashboard. What would you use in order to refresh these quantities via SignalR (not using SqlDependency)? **1)** Would you Broadcast to all clients in each of the events that cause data to change? or **2)** Would you use long polling? Any idea?

Comment: @Jack SignalR is the mechanism that sends info to the clients. It's not a genear polling, shceduling or pub/sub mechanism. If you want to poll the database for changes, create a scheduled job, task or timer that checks for changes. When those are found, SignalR can be used to push them to all the clients

Comment: @Jack SignalR has nothing to do with SqlDependency. They are *completely* different concepts. SqlDependency is about detecting changes to data. Nothing more. SignalR is about pushing messages to browser clients. That's it. **None** of them deals with polling or scheduling, except as an implementation detail used to do their job.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Many thanks for your answers. Sorry, but as I have been really too confused, I did not have enough idea about the correct mechanishm SignalR has. But with the help of Mark and your answers, now I have an idea that **when using SignalR for real-time refreshing StockExchange, Dashboard charts, etc. data I should broadcast in all of the events that cause data to change (to all of the clients), there is not a suitable approach for this scenario**. ıs that true?

Comment: I love SignalR's flexibility so much that I find it difficult for SignalR to not be a suitable approach for most tasks requiring exchange of data. I've been trying to explain that it's not that SignalR is wrong for your approach, but that your approach doesn't make the best use of SignalR. Also, I agree with all that @PanagiotisKanavos said.

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti Really useful information for me, I did not know polling in SignalR and as you said it can also be tried even if its inefficiency. In this case, assume that there is a StockExchange application where the stock quantities are displayed on a dashboard. What would you use in order to refresh these quantities via SignalR (not using SqlDependency)? 1) Would you Broadcast to all clients in each of the events that cause data to change? or 2) Would you use long polling? Any idea?

Comment: @jack: SignalR is the transport / networking library. Before you dive into that library you may want to define your basic architecture/concept. There are two main concepts: polling vs. pushing (both possible with or without SignalR). They can be enhanced with batching / caching etc. To update clients asap / "real-time" I would prefer pushing changes to the client(s). Depending on your programming style (eg. DDD, Domain-Events etc.) you can hook up polling on few central places. It all really depends what you requirements are.

Comment: @jack About your concern/pain-points: is your save/update logic cluttered all over so fear to extend all those places with calls to SignalR push?

Comment: @Marc **1)** Hi Marks. Actually I just wanted to use SignalR properly and as I have no experience I am just getting idea about which way I should go with your helps. So, as far as I see, the most common way in the usage of SignalR is broadcasting the changed data to all of the clients i.e. a Dashboard chart, StockExchange screen...

Comment: @Marc **2)** Actually I was thinking to find a way without broadcasting because I have to broadcast not only create method, also update and delete methods and for this reason tried to find a way retrieving data from all clients (maybe long polling). But I see that it is not efficient and the best way for my situation (refreshing sum, avg, total values on dashboard page) is also broadcasting new data from all of the events that cause data to change. What do you think?

Comment: @Jack I would not broadcast all types of events as it requires a lot of code and increase the coupling of the server domain-events (I think you are speaking of DDD) and the client. I would re-calculate the new totals on the server and broadcast the final numbers to the client(s). Speaking of client you can push information from the server not only to all clients but the caller, all others or any individual client. Basically you can decide to push what information to which client(s).

Comment: @Jack See here for a nice Doc about the server-api (aka SignalR Hub): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @Marc Thanks a lot Marc, the link is really very helpful. Might I also get your opinion about the 2 issues in my last comments? Your answers are really helped me so much. Thanks.

Comment: @Marc On the other hand, unfortunately I have not found an example that contains Angular + .NET MVC for SignalR and most of the examples are using .NET Core :( Can I apply the Core examples to MVC by making some modifications in the methods? And do you suggest any examples having Angular + .NET MVC for SignalR. regards.

Comment: @jack The client-side API is plain JavaScript so it should work with Angular but I never used Angular so far. I think .Net (non-Core) uses SignalR V1 instead the new V2. Not sure about this as I only have core. API in V1 is very similar to V2 and I guess docs for V1 are still online. You should be able to adapt V2 samples to V1.

Comment: @Jack About polling vs pushing. Generally speaking pushing is more efficient if you need fast updates or have lot of client because data is transferred only when needed. If you don’t have lot of clients and data most not always be up to date you also can poll once a minute or every few minutes. Polling can be done using SignalR or with plain AJAX. Polling normally is easier to implement but it does not scale well. So „it depends“ on your needs like ‚how many clients‘ and ‚how fast data must update‘.

Comment: @Marc Many thanks for your help, I really appreciated and learn something that is so important. regards...

Answer (score 2):

You can use polling with SignalR. It's just an inefficient way of doing things though, because: (1) there would be a delay between when changes happen and when they are broadcast to clients. (2) broadcasts would happen even if data didn't change, which is a waste of resources.